# How can I manage the clickaway for closing MUI dialog?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI Dialog which has to be closed when clicking away and it has a `useEffect` to close it automatically after 3 seconds.
the issue is that when I press the button `'open dialog success'` which is in a different file, the dialog doesn't open. But if I comment the `ClickAwayListener`, it opens but of course the dialog then doesn't close when clicking away.

This is my code for the dialog:

```
export const StatusModalSuccess = (): ReactElement => {
  const [openSucess, setOpenSucess] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason !== 'backdropClick') {
      setOpenSucess(false);
    }
  };
  const handleClickAway = () => {
    setOpenSucess(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // when the component is mounted, the dialog is displayed for 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOpenSucess(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Button
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        color: 'whitesmoke',
        }}
        onClick={() => { setOpenSucess(true); }}
      >
        Open dialog success
      </Button>
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
        <Dialog
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
          open={openSucess}
          PaperProps={{
            sx: {
              width: '100%',
              maxWidth: '500px!important',
              height: '100%',
              maxHeight: '250px!important',
            },
          }}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
          >
            <CheckIcon
              style={{
                color: '#2bac3d',
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                padding: 40,
              }}
            />
          </Box>
          <DialogTitle
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              paddingTop: '30px',
            }}
            id="alert-dialog-title"
          >
            <Typography variant="buttons.default">Saved successfully!</Typography>
          </DialogTitle>
        </Dialog>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `if` in `handleClose` and add `openSuccess` to the dependencies list of `useEffect`, also you don't need to use the `ClickAwayListener` component:

```
const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    setOpenSucess(false);
};

...

useEffect(() => {
  // when the component is mounted, the dialog is displayed for 3 seconds
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setOpenSucess(false);
  }, 3000);

  return () => { clearTimeout(timer) }
}, [openSucess]);

return (
    <Stack>
      <Button
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: "green",
          color: "whitesmoke"
        }}
        onClick={() => {
          setOpenSucess(true);
        }}
      >
        Open dialog success
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        open={openSucess}
        PaperProps={{
          sx: {
            width: "100%",
            maxWidth: "500px!important",
            height: "100%",
            maxHeight: "250px!important"
          }
        }}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
      ...
```

Comment: Your answer perfectly works but now the useEffect doesn't work as expected. I nee to close the dialog after 3 seconds. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Add `openSucess` to the dependencies list of useEffect: `, [openSucess])`

Comment: @mariadev don't forget to clear the timeout in `useEffect`, check my update